# How to handle multiprocessing based on the limit of CPU's

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently i have a process that parses thousands of data files, currently I'm doing the following strategy to limit the number of parallel process launched based if the total amount is lower than  the number of CPUs available.

But this is the most apropriate  way to do it?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def pool_executor(function_name, data):
    if len(data) >= 8:
        workers = cpu_count()
    else:
        workers = len(data)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        executor.map(function_name, data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just pass in `cpu_count()` for the `max_workers` value. If `len(data)` is less than that it won't create more workers than it needs.

```
def pool_executor(function_name, data):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count()) as executor:
        executor.map(function_name, data)
```

However you might want to experiment to find whether `cpu_count()` is actually the best value. If your processes are spending a lot of time reading/writing files it might be that starting slightly more than `cpu_count()` actually gives you an additional boost, but that's only something you can determine from measurement.